# I am having trouble with if/else statement using JOptionPane?

Tags: java

The question is:

> Q.Write a program using dialog boxes that prompts the user to make a choice for a pizza 
>   size  –  S,  M,  L,  or  X  –  and  then  displays  the  price  as  $6.99,  $8.99,  $12.50,  or  $15.00 accordingly. Save the program as PizzaChoice.java.

This question I need to do with the if/else statement, using dialog boxes, by JOptionPane.

```
public class PizzaChoice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String choice;
    String small;      
    String medium;
    String extraLarge;

    choice= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter yur choice of pizza :"+" S, M, L, X");
    double s,S;
    //double s2= Double.parseDouble(small);

    if(s==S ){
        System.out.println("$6.99"+s);
    }

    }
}
```

I can't get further than this. I tried many different ways, but still cannot code well.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is homework, I'm not giving you the whole code. There is a nice way of doing this with an option dialog.

```
String[] pizzaSizes = {"Small", "Medium", ....};
int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Make your choise", "Pizza size", 0, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, pizzaSizes, null};
```

The `option` variable is the index for the chosen pizza in the pizzaSizes array.

Now, you can make a parallel array with the prices.

```
String[] prices = {"$ 6.99", ... };
```

Now, the message for the displaying the price is as simple as this. (It doesn't uses ifs, but I like this more than working with if/else):

```
String message = "Pizza " + pizzaSizes[option] + " costs " + prices[option] + ".");
```

Comment: @MushfiqurrahmanSajid: When someone helped you out, you can accepted the answer that helped you by clicking the tick under the score of the answer. It will become green, now you question is marked as solved.

Comment: O sorry, I didn't knew the rules, I really didn't knew it. Sorry! And thanx, to all of you, for your help. :-)

Comment: @MushfiqurrahmanSajid: Now, you know the rules, you can apply them, by clicking the tick next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The user's choice is actually stored in the variable that you put the `JOptionPane` on the right hand side, which is aptly named `choice`.

Try something like this:

```
String small = "S";
.
.
.
String choice; 
double price = 0.0;
choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter yur choice of pizza :"+" S, M, L, X");

if(choice.equals(small))
{
   price = ....;
}
```